# how to pass dijit/form/DateTextBox value into json in declaratively in Dojo?

Tags: dojo

I need to parse this alert message into JSON string.

alert(dojo.date.locale.format(dijit.byId('sampleDate').value,{datePattern: "yyyy-MM-dd", selector: "date"}));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.parse()?

```
require(["dojo/json"], function(JSON){
  alert(JSON.parse(dojo.date.locale.format(dijit.byId('sampleDate').value,{datePattern: "yyyy-MM-dd", selector: "date"}),true));
});
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/json.html